# Can't include wildcards when creating a tag link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I wanted to create a tag link including a wild card:

```
[tag:google*]
```

but when I typed it I got:

[tag:google*]

i.e. Nothing.

It wasn't converted into a tag link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As balpha [mentions on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140525/markdown-cant-handle-tags-with-asterisks/140528#140528), the `[tag:]` syntax is intentionally designed to link to a specific tag, making this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).